# Como construir tabelas do teste de Tukey no R

Tags: r, tabela-html

Tenho várias análises do teste de Tukey feitas no R e gostaria de transformar as tabelas obtidas em tabelas com o aspecto que se pode ver na imagem. Existe alguma forma mais ou menos automática para fazer isso? 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Cátia, bem vinda ao SO. Você pode incluir na pergunta uma amostra dos seus dados e o código que utilizou para gerar as tabelas? Basta o exemplo de uma das suas tabelas. Isso facilita para quem for responder sua pergunta. Veja na ajuda do site como fazer para criar um exemplo que os outros usuários podem reproduzir: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1):

Acho que esse link resolve seu problema

https://www.r-bloggers.com/anova-and-tukeys-test-on-r/